# Echo row of mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following MySQL query and I want to echo a specific row when a condition is satisfied;

```
global $post;
$post_author = $post->post_author;
$result = mysql_query("SELECT *, @rownum := @rownum + 1 from
    (
    SELECT (display_name) 'Author',
        IFNULL(ROUND(SUM(balance.meta_value),2),2) 'Balance'
    FROM posts p
    JOIN users u 
        ON p.post_author = u.ID
    JOIN postmeta odd ON p.ID = odd.post_id AND odd.meta_key = 'odd' AND odd.meta_value >= 1.5
    LEFT JOIN postmeta balance 
        ON p.ID = balance.post_id AND balance.meta_key = 'balance'
    WHERE p.post_status = 'publish'
    GROUP BY u.ID
    ORDER BY Balanco DESC
    )x, (SELECT @rownum := 0) r");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

I want to echo row 3 when the Author equals $post_author, can someone help me with this. Thanks.

```
<?php echo "{$row[3]}";?> where Author=$post_author
```

Comment: Consider providing an sqlfiddle, together with the desired result set.

Comment: do you want all the rows or just the row whose display_name equals $post_author

Comment: I want the row specific for the post_author, which I get from $post_author = $post->post_author;

Comment: Why not just add author name condition in your sql query ?

Comment: Why do you not filter in the SELECT?

Comment: I want to get the rank, if I do that I'll always get -> 1

Comment: `WHERE p.post_status = 'publish' AND p.post_author=$post_author`  guessing thats injection friendly but you can fix that :)

Comment: Which column contains author name ?

Comment: @furas - first column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe a simple `if` would make you happy:

```
if ($row[0] == $post_author)
    echo $row[3];
```

Comment: it doesn't work, it's doesn't echo anything. What I need is to echo row 3 when row 0 = post_author

Comment: Are you sure it's `$row[3]`? Maybe the info you need is in `$row[1]` or `$row[2]`? Instead of `echo $row[3];` try `var_dump($row);`